# How to configure Celery Worker and Beat for Email Reporting in Apache Superset running on Docker?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, celery, apache-superset

I am running Superset via Docker. I enabled the Email Report feature and tried it:

[image]

However, I only receive the test email report. I don't receive any emails after.

This is my CeleryConfig in superset_config.py:

```
class CeleryConfig(object):
    BROKER_URL = 'sqla+postgresql://superset:superset@db:5432/superset'
    CELERY_IMPORTS = (
        'superset.sql_lab',
        'superset.tasks',
    )
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+postgresql://superset:superset@db:5432/superset'
    CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'
    CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 10
    CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
    CELERY_ANNOTATIONS = {
        'sql_lab.get_sql_results': {
            'rate_limit': '100/s',
        },
        'email_reports.send': {
            'rate_limit': '1/s',
            'time_limit': 120,
            'soft_time_limit': 150,
            'ignore_result': True,
        },
    }
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
        'email_reports.schedule_hourly': {
            'task': 'email_reports.schedule_hourly',
            'schedule': crontab(minute=1, hour='*'),
        },
    }
```

The [documentation](https://superset.apache.org/installation.html#email-reports) says I need to run the celery worker and beat.

```
celery worker --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app --pool=prefork -O fair -c 4
celery beat --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app
```

I added them to the '[docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)':

```
superset-worker:
    build: *superset-build
    command: >
      sh -c "celery worker --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app -Ofair -f /app/celery_worker.log &&
             celery beat --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app -f /app/celery_beat.log"
    env_file: docker/.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    volumes: *superset-volumes
```

Celery Worker is indeed working when sending the first email. The log file is also visible. However, the celery beat seems to not be functioning. There is also no 'celery_beat.log' created.

If you'd like a deeper insight, [here's the commit](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/pull/5294/commits/74e8b29483a9cd6ad00a9bbc9f6aa69467baad9a) with the full implementation of the functionality.

How do I correctly configure celery beat? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it by altering the `CeleryConfig` implementation, and adding a beat service to 'docker-compose.yml'

New `CeleryConfig` class in 'superset_config.py':

```
REDIS_HOST = get_env_variable("REDIS_HOST")
REDIS_PORT = get_env_variable("REDIS_PORT")

class CeleryConfig(object):
    BROKER_URL = "redis://%s:%s/0" % (REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT)
    CELERY_IMPORTS = (
        'superset.sql_lab',
        'superset.tasks',
    )
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://%s:%s/1" % (REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT)
    CELERY_ANNOTATIONS = {
        'sql_lab.get_sql_results': {
            'rate_limit': '100/s',
        },
        'email_reports.send': {
            'rate_limit': '1/s',
            'time_limit': 120,
            'soft_time_limit': 150,
            'ignore_result': True,
        },
    }
    CELERY_TASK_PROTOCOL = 1
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
        'email_reports.schedule_hourly': {
            'task': 'email_reports.schedule_hourly',
            'schedule': crontab(minute='1', hour='*'),
        },
    }
```

Changes in 'docker-compose.yml':

```
  superset-worker:
    build: *superset-build
    command: ["celery", "worker", "--app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app", "-Ofair"]
    env_file: docker/.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    volumes: *superset-volumes

  superset-beat:
    build: *superset-build
    command: ["celery", "beat", "--app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app", "--pidfile=", "-f", "/app/celery_beat.log"]
    env_file: docker/.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    volumes: *superset-volumes
```

Comment: what is superset-build?.. Is the config outdated?

Comment: @d9k this was pre superset 1.0. superset-build corresponds to the versions prior 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Celery needs to run inside your superset container - so you'll need to modify your dockerfile and entrypoint. 
BUT you should really first daemonize celery so you don't have to monitor and restart celery [see [how to detect failure and auto restart celery worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861717/how-to-detect-failure-and-auto-restart-celery-worker) and http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html].
See an example here for how to run a daemonized celery process in docker: [Docker - Celery as a daemon - no pidfiles found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410013/docker-celery-as-a-daemon-no-pidfiles-found)

Answer (score 0):

you can also add `-B` flag to celery worker command to run beat

```
celery worker --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app --pool=prefork -O fair -c 4 -B
```

Comment: that's not recommended in production, when you have multiple workers

Comment: It is better then two separate command/processes in docker. 
I have 1,5 year of -B in prod,  all fine.

Comment: how many workers do you have running? The [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler) say "You can also embed beat inside the worker by enabling the workers -B option, this is convenient if you’ll never run more than one worker node, but it’s not commonly used and for that reason isn’t recommended for production use"

Comment: If you have only one worker then fine, but you shouldn't use -B for multiple workers

Comment: there were 6 containers with diffirent params for workers and one of them was with -B option and all works fine

Comment: @RyabchenkoAlexander need help in some mail setup , can you help?